# What exactly is the difference between PATH (as set by setenv) and exec-path in GNU Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Well, the title has it all.  I used to `(setenv "PATH" "whatever:$PATH" t)` to be able to call things (in fact, one thing - ConTeXt, from within AUCTeX) from Emacs.  Just a while ago I learned about `exec-path`.  Should I use it instead?

Answer (score 7):

While `setenv` actually sets the environment (and affect (modifies) what executed programs from this emacs will see as an environment), `exec-path` tells emacs where to look for executables, but programs run from this emacs won't see their `PATH` changed.

Changing the environment with `setenv` does not change how the current Emacs searchs for executables, as it uses `exec-path`. To achieve that *and* make child processes executed by this Emacs to have the `$PATH` changed, you have to set both `exec-path` and `$PATH`.